# Remove leading + or 00 from number using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove + or 00 from the beginning of a number in case they exist. So a number like `+37253783478` would output `37253783478` and `0037253783478` would output `37253783478`. What would the regex look like that matches this pattern?

**EDIT:** I've managed to remove the leading zeros using `^0+` but I can't figure out how to match both cases.

Comment: What have you tried thus far?

Comment: @Nick I've managed to match the leading zeroes using ^0+ but I can't figure out how to match both cases.

Comment: By the way, the reason your post is getting downvoted is because you should generally add what you've tried to your problem description. Unfortunately, people here just assume that, if you don't, you're just trying to get people to do your work for you (I tend to just ask what you've tried rather than making the assumption). All that being said, can you add what you had tried to your problem description?

Comment: Depending on your use cases, matching `^[+0]+` and replacing by the empty string could work.

Comment: Please try adding the regex you are currenlty using and a sample of the current string and the result you're expecting. In short: "Please elaborate"

Comment: where is your existing regex that you have build so far, you should add it in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the requirement, the following will match both cases. Essentially, what you need to do is use the regex or operator `|`.

The following will remove all leading 0s

```
str.replace(/(^0+|^\+)/,'')
```

But if you just need to remove exactly two leading 0s, use this:

```
str.replace(/(^00|^\+)/,'')
```

And here it is in action on your examples:

```js
let nums = ['+37253783478', '0037253783478', '0037253780478', '375378+0478'];
let replaced = nums.map(num => num.replace(/(^0+|^\+)/,''));
console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: I think it should be ```str.replace(/(^00|^\+)/g,'');```. Your code does also remove the zero in 037253783478 and removes all three zeroes in 00037253783478

Comment: Ah I was in the middle of simplifying the regex, although I'm not sure about the 00 piece, I can't tell if all leading 0s should be removed or just the two.

Comment: @flappix also, the `/g` is not necessary in this case, right?